# jquery css default font size

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form that allows the user to push an up or down button to resize the font in an element. When I reset the form I need to put the "default" font size back in a hidden field to send to a php script. So how can I get the css font size actually typed into the css stylesheet, not the one that has been altered by jquery?

Thank you,
Todd

Comment: Where is the code that resizes it?  What is the purpose of getting the default value, just to reset the presentation?

Comment: yes, to reset everything as in a 'fresh' reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the default font size in your css like so:

```
#myelement {
    font-size: 12;
}
```

Then you can override this value locally by using javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');
element.style.fontSize = new_font_size;  // local values override the value from the stylesheet.
```

Then when you want to set it to the default

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');
element.style.fontSize = null; // now it reverts back to using the value defined in the stylesheet
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to store the original font size before you change it:

```
var originalFontSize = $myElement.css('font-size');
```

Then in your code for resetting the form:

```
$myHiddenElement.attr('value', originalFontSize);
```

You *can* access definitions within the actual stylesheet using Javascript - described [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml) - but then you'd have to make all sorts of assumptions about where the relevant definition for your element is located and wouldn't take into account any browser-specific overrides etc. It's much easier to just grab the state of that element before you modify it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but it seemed a little wrong. It is probably the easiest and most reliable. Thanks.

Comment: @maddogandnoriko - See Steve's answer below - he's shown that setting the `fontSize` property to `null` reverts it to its stylesheet value. It might be more compatible across browsers to use jQuery's version of this, i.e. `$myElement.css('font-size', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default value in JS variable before changing font-size.

```
var defaultFontSize = 20;
```

And then use it to do reset.

Comment: but then if I change it in the stylesheet down the road I will have to remember to change it in the js also....

Comment: undetermined....but if I decide to change it a year from now I am likely to forget to change it in both places